# How to add Toast Notification after pressing button certain times

Tags: android, button

I want to add a toast notification to my app which has a submit button. When a user hit the button it shows a message which it fetches from a JSON file. I want that whenever anyone press that button 5th time a toast notification appear there.

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a global counter?

```
int count = 0;

...

public void onClick() { //Button press callback

    //Do other things...

    if (count == 5) {
        Toast.makeToast(this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    count++;

}
```

Adapt to your application, but that's the gist of it.